# What is the physical difference between the Euclidean and the Lorentzian path integral?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, wick-rotation

This is a specific example of the broader question of why should physics change with metric signature basically.

Based on a talk by Daniel Harlow, I am generally wondering what exactly makes the Euclidean path integral different from the Lorentzian one? Why does the signature matter and what physical changes does it have as a consequence? Also, I haveread that the Euclidean case is simpler to deal with in technical computations than the Lorentzian one, but I cannot find any specific examples of this and I don't understand how the reparametrization  $\,t\rightarrow -i\tau$ can make such a big difference. In general, when should I use one or the other when tackling a problem?

Answer (score 3):

The Euclidean path integral usually has no physical meaning (unless you really are interested in non-relativistic Euclidean physics, but then why would you be thinking about Lorentzian integrals at all?). The Euclidean formulation is "easier" since integrals involving real exponential factors like $\mathrm{e}^{-S}$ have better convergence behaviour than those with imaginary oscillatory factors $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}S}$.

In general, the difference between the Euclidean and Lorentzian theories is *huge* - one describes a universe with finite speed of massless objects and the other doesn't, for one. It is not intuitively obvious that the Euclidean theory should have anything to say about the Lorentzian theory! The actual argument that tells us that the analytic continuation of the Euclidean correlation functions really does yield the correct Lorentzian correlation functions is the [Osterwalder-Schrader reconstruction theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Osterwalder-Schrader+theorem).